# An elementary approach of proving $\int_0^1\frac{6dx}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^3)(2-x^3)^2}}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)^2}}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was told that $$\int_0^1\frac{6dx}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^3)(2-x^3)^2}}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)^2}}.$$
I am able to prove this identity through hypergeometric functions.

> **My approach**
>   $$\begin{aligned}LHS&=\int_0^1\frac{2dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)(2-x)^2}}\\&=\int_0^1\frac{2^{1/3}dx}{x^{2/3}(1-x)^{1/3}(1-x/2)^{2/3}}\\
> &=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\cdot2^{1/3}{}_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;\frac12\right)\\
> &=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\cdot2^{1/3}\frac{3\Gamma^3(1/3)}{2^{7/3}\pi^2}\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt3\Gamma^3(1/3)}{2\pi}=B\left(\frac13,\frac13\right)=RHS\end{aligned}$$
>   as
>   $$_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;1;\frac12\right)=\sqrt[3]2\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac13;1;-1\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma(2/3) \Gamma(5/6)}$$

So my question is: by observing this "simple" identity, there seems to be an elementary substitution way to prove this identity without using this complicated method. Can we prove it using substitution, integrating by parts or other elementary tricks only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sub $x = \left ( 1-\sqrt{y} \right )^{1/3}$.  I think you can take it from there.